# Must all operators be Unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, unitarity

Do all operators on a quantum state have to be unitary? Does this mean that there are non-unitary operators that act on quantum states in real life?

Context:
Let's say we have a composite quantum system made up on 2 entangled states (A and B). Let's say the systems are maximally entangled (composite state = singlet). The quantum system was created in an entangled state here on Earth, and one of the sub-systems (B) was sent to another galaxy.

If A's state them undergoes state transformations under unitary operators, the statistical model of both A and B remain the same after the transformations. This is great, and means there is no "instantaneous" transmission of information.

If the operators are however not unitary, my understanding is that such transformations can impact the statistical model of the quantum state of a system (the expected value of some observable can change). And given that A and B are entangled, B's statistical model also needs to change.

Comment: Did you mean a quantum operation rather than a quantum operator?

Comment: Look at this post. It might help you: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/136/

Comment: @skittish this is a good observation and in fact not all time evolution operators are unitary. Well, to say that they are "operators" is actually not even sufficient anymore! Necessarily, since it is a subsystem of the whole, the system must be represented instead by a density matrix. And the most general operation on a density matrix $\rho$ is not $M\rho M^{\dagger}$. Instead, it is a sum of terms of that form (that is why Qmechanic mentions "quantum operation"). Have a look at the Kraus Representation Theorem (Kraus' Theorem). Imo your question was clear enough. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯